# How can I inspect a backed up .TRN File?

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging, transactions

Trying to figure out when and how some data was deleted from our database.  We save a backup of all TRN files, there is a TRN file available for approx. every 15 minutes.

Already tried the `fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)` function but there are no logs corresponding to the table in question.

Tried SysTools Log Analyzer but it doesn;t support TRN files.

Tried ApexSQL but only works on live databases.

Is it possible to take an individual .TRN file and read it?  If so, how?

EDIT

We restored the database and incrementally applied the logs until we found the right one.  We know which log file that the delete command is in, but when we run `fn_dblog(NULL<NULL)` there are no records for the table in question.

Comment: Was the log file that was active during the delete backed up perhaps? If so, you could do a piecemeal restore on a test box until you found it.

Comment: Yes it was backed up.  We have done a piecemeal restore as you suggest to pinpoint the log file that contains the delete.  I want to view the contents of this single log file to see the transaction details.

Comment: If `fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)` didn't contain it, how do you know you have the right .trn file? Just wondering since you said *Trying to figure out when and how some data was deleted*

Comment: When we run `fn_dblog(NULL,NULL)`, does it only show records from the most recently applied log file?  For example, if we restore the database and apply log files 1,2  and 3, will the function only look at log file 3?

Comment: Did you try fn_dump_dblog? https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/using-fn_dblog-fn_dump_dblog-and-restoring-with-stopbeforemark-to-an-lsn/